# Docusign - How do I send a document to multiple signers and have them sign on the document through API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, docusignapi

I  would like to send a document out to multiple people.

1. Requestor sends document to Approver-1. Approver-1 reviews and signs the document
2. Approver-2 receives the signed document(signed by Approver-1) , reviews and signs on the same document
   How is it possible with DocuSign using docusign API.

With only one signer,it is working fine. How to make it work for multiple signers.

Here is the request body that I am using for API

```
url = Constants.DocusignURL + "/accounts/" + Constants.DocusignAccountId + "/envelopes";

var templateRole = "Signer"
var requestBody = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                                    "<status>sent</status>" +
                                    "<emailSubject>" + subjectText + "</emailSubject>" +
                                    "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" +
                                    "<templateRoles>" +
                                    "<templateRole>" +
                                            "<name>" + recipeintName + "</name>" +
                                            "<email>" + recipientEmail + "</email>" +
                                            "<roleName>" + templateRole + "</roleName>" +
                                            "<tabs>" +
                                                "<textTabs>" +
                                                    "Test"
                                                "</textTabs>" +                                                                       
                                             "</tabs>" +
                                        "</templateRole>" +
                                    "</templateRoles>" +                     
                                "</envelopeDefinition>"
```

Not sure how to add multiple signers to request body

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the `routingOrder` for the templateRole.

Have a look at the [Sample Request with Multiple Recipients](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/recipients#sample-request-with-multiple-recipients) on the DocuSign website.

Taking an educated guess (as I'm using the [C# client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/), so slightly different syntax), but you'll need something that looks like this:

```
<templateRoles>
  <templateRole>
    <name>First Signer</name>
    <email>first.signer@example.com</email>
    <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
  </templateRole>
  <templateRole>
   <name>Second Signer</name>
   <email>second.signer@example.com</email>
   <routingOrder>2</routingOrder>
  </templateRole>    
</templateRoles>
```

Comment: Also do we need to specify <roleName> element inside templateRole node?